# Drupal - creating entries in file_managed

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom content type with 2 custom fields: file (file) and list (status).

I can set the value of status by doing:

```
 $node = node_load($n, $r);
 $node->field_status[$node->language][0]['value'] = 1;
 node_save($node);
```

I want to create entries for field_file and file_managed (core table) for a file that is ALREADY on the server. I already know the MIME type, size and path of the file.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: is it in the file_managed table as well?

Comment: No, the file gets onto the server via a 3rd party application. The information about the file is accessible via an XML file Drupal is aware of. So the data from XML needs to be put into file_managed AND field_file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would instantiate the file object manually and use [`file_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save/7) to commit it (using an image file as an example):

```
global $user;
$file = new stdClass;
$file->uid = $user->uid;
$file->filename = 'image.png';
$file->uri = 'public://path/to/file/image.png';
$file->status = 1;
$file->filemime = 'image/png';

file_save($file);
```

You should then call [`file_usage_add()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7) to let Drupal know your module has a vested interest in this file (using the `nid` from your `$node` object):

```
file_usage_add($file, 'mymodule', 'node', $node->nid);
```

Finally you can add the file to the node:

```
$node->field_file[$node->language][] = array(
  'fid' => $file->fid
);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think Drupal creates the file_usage entry when you save an entity with a file field that uses the file, so you don't need to call `file_usage_add()` yourself.